# Unable to create Liferay project from plugins SDK with error "app.server.dir is invalid"

Tags: liferay, liferay-ide

I have installed Liferay7.0 successfully and then was trying to import Liferay SDK plugins. I am using Liferay supported IDE(Downloaded from Liferay website) Neon.3[image]

I have tried reinstalling Liferay, but it didn't work.
Sdk version is also 7.0. 
Please help to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a good reason to use Plugin SDK in Liferay 7, you should use Liferay Workspace (or maven or gradle). Plugin SDK is basically only for upgrading legacy plugins, but new work is better documented and more flexible in the new OSGi modules.

As you state that your Plugin SDK is version 7, you're probably not upgrading. Instead of fixing your issue, simply ignore the SDK. If you want to fix it: Just like the previous versions' Plugin SDKs you'll need to configure the location of Liferay in build.*yourusername*.properties in the root folder of the SDK. (replace *yourusername* with the actual name that you're using to login to your development machine). The configuration you need is stated in the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

focus on error message, please make a file name with your [USER-NAME] like this "build.[USER-NAME].properties" (ex: build.sam.properties) contain bellow properties and put in Liferay SDK path
(I put it in eclipse/plugins/com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-7.0/

contain:

```
liferay.dir = C:/
app.server.type = tomcat
app.server = tomcat-8.0.32
app.server.parent.dir = ${liferay.dir}/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3
app.server.tomcat.dir = ${app.server.parent.dir}/${app.server}
app.server.portal.dir = ${app.server.tomcat.dir}/webapps/ROOT
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using wildfly server, use the following in your `build.user.name.properties` file. (Location ex: C:..\com.liferay.portal.plugins.sdk-7.0)

```
app.server.parent.dir =C:/../liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3

app.server.type=wildfly
app.server.wildfly.dir=${app.server.parent.dir}/wildfly-10.0.0
app.server.wildfly.deploy.dir=${app.server.wildfly.dir}/standalone/deployments
app.server.wildfly.lib.global.dir=${app.server.wildfly.dir}/modules/com/liferay/portal/main
app.server.wildfly.portal.dir=${app.server.wildfly.dir}/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war
```